# xslt how to merge product nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

i need to merge shop products which contains size in name. As you can see i have to cut size from product name and put it to new element inside group-element "SIZES", the same thing with PARTNO and STOCK which are needed to identify product, his sizes and quantity. I created some xslt with template and foreach loop but i dont know how to verify if some node was created before.

Its very important for me because xslt is my new resposibility in my job, im new with xslt so my code is very simple and ugly.

here is example xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
    <SHOP xmlns="http://www.b2b.abisaltest.pl">
       <SHOPITEM>
          <PRODUCT>ZBRS180 CZERWONA BRAMKA PIŁKARSKA</PRODUCT>
          <PRICE>167.01</PRICE>
          <PARTNO>5907695527654</PARTNO>
          <STOCK>177</STOCK>
       </SHOPITEM>
       <SHOPITEM>
          <PRODUCT>NJ2117 A NIEBIESKO-RÓŻOWE SIZE. M (34-37)  ŁYŻWOROLKI NILS 
           EXTREME</PRODUCT>
          <PRICE>113.01</PRICE>
          <PARTNO>5907695510333</PARTNO>
          <STOCK>158</STOCK>
       </SHOPITEM>
       <SHOPITEM>
          <PRODUCT>NJ2117 A NIEBIESKO-RÓŻOWE SIZE. L (38-41)  ŁYŻWOROLKI NILS 
          EXTREME</PRODUCT>
          <PRICE>113.01</PRICE>
          <PARTNO>5907695510334</PARTNO>
          <STOCK>35</STOCK>
       </SHOPITEM>
    </SHOP>

**Output file should looks like that:**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
    <SHOP>
       <SHOPITEM>
          <PRODUCT>ZBRS180 CZERWONA BRAMKA PIŁKARSKA</PRODUCT>
          <PRICE>167.01</PRICE>
          <PARTNO>5907695527654</PARTNO>
          <STOCK>177</STOCK>
       </SHOPITEM>
       <SHOPITEM>
          <PRODUCT>NJ2117 A NIEBIESKO-RÓŻOWE ŁYŻWOROLKI NILS EXTREME</PRODUCT>
          <SIZES>
             <SIZE>M (34-37)</SIZE>
             <SIZE>L (38-41)</SIZE>
          </SIZES>
          <PARTNOS>
            <PARTNO>5907695510333</PARTNO>
            <PARTNO>5907695510334</PARTNO>
          </PARTNOS>
          <STOCKS>
            <STOCK>158</STOCK>
            <STOCK>35</STOCK>
          </STOCKS>
          <PRICE>113.01</PRICE>
       </SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```

Here is my xsl code:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:abi="http://www.b2b.abisaltest.pl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"/>


      <xsl:template match="abi:SHOP">
        <xsl:element name="SHOP">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="abi:SHOPITEM">
          <xsl:with-param name="pNodeset" select="abi:SHOPITEM"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>




<xsl:template match="abi:SHOPITEM">
    <xsl:param name="pNodeset" />
    <xsl:element name="SHOPITEM" >
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(abi:PRODUCT/text(), 'SIZE.')">
                <!-- Creating variable with node name -->
                <xsl:variable name="currentCuttedNodeName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(abi:PRODUCT/text(), 'SIZE.')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <!-- Looking for SIZES -->
                <xsl:element name="SIZES">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$pNodeset">
                        <xsl:if test="contains(abi:PRODUCT/text(), $currentCuttedNodeName)">
                            <xsl:element name="SIZE">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="contains(abi:PRODUCT/text(),')')">
                                        <xsl:variable name="from">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-before(abi:PRODUCT/text(), '('))+1"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:variable name="to">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-before(abi:PRODUCT/text(), ')'))"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(abi:PRODUCT/text(),$from,7)"/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:variable name="from">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-before(abi:PRODUCT/text(), 'SIZE.'))"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(abi:PRODUCT/text(),$from+7, 2)"/>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
                <!-- Looking for EANS -->
                <xsl:element name="EANS">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$pNodeset">
                        <xsl:if test="contains(abi:PRODUCT/text(), $currentCuttedNodeName)">
                            <xsl:element name="EAN">
                                <xsl:value-of select="abi:PARTNO/text()"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
                <!-- Looking for external codes -->
                <xsl:element name="CODES">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$pNodeset">
                        <xsl:if test="contains(abi:PRODUCT/text(), $currentCuttedNodeName)">
                            <xsl:element name="CODE">
                                <xsl:value-of select="abi:PRODUCTNO/text()"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
                <!-- Looking for stocks -->
                <xsl:element name="STOCKS">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$pNodeset">
                        <xsl:if test="contains(abi:PRODUCT/text(), $currentCuttedNodeName)">
                            <xsl:element name="STOCK">
                                <xsl:value-of select="abi:STOCK/text()"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="NAME">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="contains(abi:PRODUCT/text(),')')">
                                        <xsl:variable name="from">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-before(abi:PRODUCT/text(), 'SIZE.'))"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:variable name="to">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-before(abi:PRODUCT/text(), ')'))"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:variable name="firstPart">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(abi:PRODUCT/text(),'SIZE.')"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:variable name="secondPart">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(abi:PRODUCT/text(),')')"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($firstPart,$secondPart)"/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:variable name="firstPart">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(abi:PRODUCT/text(), 'SIZE.')"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:variable name="fromNumber">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-after(abi:PRODUCT/text(), 'SIZE.')) +10"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:variable name="secondPart">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="substring(abi:PRODUCT/text(), $fromNumber, string-length(abi:PRODUCT/text()) - $fromNumber)"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($firstPart, $secondPart)"/>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="ID">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="DESC">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:DESCRIPTION/text()"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="IMGURL">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:IMGURL"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="BRAND">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:BRAND"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- Filling elements to no size item -->
                <xsl:element name="SIZES">
                    <xsl:element name="SIZE">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Uniwersalny'"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="EANS">
                    <xsl:element name="EAN">
                        <xsl:value-of select="abi:PARTNO/text()"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="CODES">
                    <xsl:element name="CODE">
                        <xsl:value-of select="abi:PRODUCTNO/text()"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="STOCKS">
                    <xsl:element name="STOCK">
                        <xsl:value-of select="abi:STOCK/text()"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="NAME">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:PRODUCT/text()"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="ID">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="DESC">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:DESCRIPTION/text()"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="IMGURL">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:IMGURL"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="BRAND">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:BRAND"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html -- P.S. Would it be correct to assume that the first word in `PRODUCT` is the unique identifier of the product?

Comment: Yes, first word of PRODUCT is only unique value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:abi="http://www.b2b.abisaltest.pl"
exclude-result-prefixes="abi">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"/>

<xsl:key name="qualifierKey" match="/abi:SHOP/abi:SHOPITEM" use="concat(substring-before(abi:PRODUCT,'SIZE.'),substring-after(abi:PRODUCT,')'))" />

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="abi:SHOP">
    <xsl:element name="SHOP">
        <xsl:for-each select="abi:SHOPITEM[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('qualifierKey', concat(substring-before(abi:PRODUCT,'SIZE.'),substring-after(abi:PRODUCT,')')))[1])]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="abi:SHOPITEM">
    <SHOPITEM>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(abi:PRODUCT, 'SIZE.')">
                <xsl:element name="PRODUCT">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(abi:PRODUCT,'SIZE.'),substring-after(abi:PRODUCT,')'))" />
                </xsl:element>      

                <!-- Looking for SIZES -->
                <xsl:element name="SIZES">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('qualifierKey', concat(substring-before(abi:PRODUCT,'SIZE.'),substring-after(abi:PRODUCT,')')))">
                        <xsl:element name="SIZE">
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(substring-after(substring-before(abi:PRODUCT,')'),'SIZE.'), ')'))" />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>

                <!-- Looking for EANS -->
                <xsl:element name="PARTNOS">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('qualifierKey', concat(substring-before(abi:PRODUCT,'SIZE.'),substring-after(abi:PRODUCT,')')))">
                        <xsl:if test="abi:PARTNO != ''">
                            <xsl:element name="PARTNO">
                                <xsl:value-of select="abi:PARTNO/text()" />
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>

                <!-- Looking for stocks -->
                <xsl:element name="STOCKS">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('qualifierKey', concat(substring-before(abi:PRODUCT,'SIZE.'),substring-after(abi:PRODUCT,')')))">
                        <xsl:if test="abi:STOCK != ''">
                            <xsl:element name="STOCK">
                                <xsl:value-of select="abi:STOCK/text()" />
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>

                <!-- Looking for external codes -->
                <xsl:element name="CODES">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('qualifierKey', concat(substring-before(abi:PRODUCT,'SIZE.'),substring-after(abi:PRODUCT,')')))">
                        <xsl:if test="abi:PRODUCTNO != ''">
                            <xsl:element name="CODE">
                                <xsl:value-of select="abi:PRODUCTNO/text()" />
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="PRICE">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:PRICE" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="ID">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="DESC">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:DESCRIPTION/text()" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="IMGURL">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:IMGURL" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="BRAND">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:BRAND" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="PRODUCT">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:PRODUCT/text()" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="PRICE">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:PRICE" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="PARTNO">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:PARTNO/text()" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="STOCK">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:STOCK/text()" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="SIZE">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Uniwersalny'" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="CODE">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:PRODUCTNO/text()" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="ID">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="DESC">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:DESCRIPTION/text()" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="IMGURL">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:IMGURL" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="BRAND">
                    <xsl:value-of select="abi:BRAND" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </SHOPITEM>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfg

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly simple - but I think it could be much simpler than what you're trying to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:abi="http://www.b2b.abisaltest.pl"
exclude-result-prefixes="abi">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="item" match="abi:SHOPITEM" use="substring-before(abi:PRODUCT, ' ')" />

<xsl:template match="/abi:SHOP">
    <SHOP>
        <!-- MUENCHIAN GROUPING -->
        <xsl:for-each select="abi:SHOPITEM[count(. | key('item', substring-before(abi:PRODUCT, ' '))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('item', substring-before(abi:PRODUCT, ' '))" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count($current-group) > 1">
                    <SHOPITEM>
                        <PRODUCT>
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(abi:PRODUCT, 'SIZE.')"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(abi:PRODUCT, 'SIZE. '), ')')"/>                                                   
                        </PRODUCT>
                        <SIZES>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$current-group">
                                <SIZE>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(abi:PRODUCT, 'SIZE. '), ')')"/>
                                    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
                                </SIZE>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </SIZES>
                        <PARTNOS>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="$current-group/abi:PARTNO"/>
                        </PARTNOS>
                        <STOCKS>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="$current-group/abi:STOCK"/>
                        </STOCKS>
                     </SHOPITEM>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$current-group"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </SHOP>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="abi:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```